# Struggling with parameter count, command tree

Tags: javascript

Basically what I'm trying to acheive in javascript, looks like this in C# :

```
private void ilevel(CommandArgs args)
    {

        if (args.Parameters.Count < 1)
        {
            args.Player.SendInfoMessage("Info: /ilevel subcmd1");
            args.Player.SendInfoMessage("Info: /ilevel subcmd2");

        }

        switch (args.Parameters[0])
        {
            case "subcmd1":
                {
                    args.Player.SendInfoMessage("message1", Color.SkyBlue);
                    args.Player.SendInfoMessage("message2");
                    args.Player.SendInfoMessage("message3");

                }
                break;

            case "subcmd2":
                {
                    args.Player.SendInfoMessage("message1", Color.SkyBlue);
                    args.Player.SendInfoMessage("message2");
                    args.Player.SendInfoMessage("message3");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Now the javascript looks like this:

```
var plr;
var ilevelCommand = acmd_alias_create("ilevel", 0, 0, "", function(player, args) {
plr = player;
ilevelSwitch(player, args);
});

var Ilevelcolor = "250,250,47";

function trace(msg) {
tshock_msg_color(Ilevelcolor, plr, msg);
}
function ilevelSwitch(player, args) {
    if (args <1)
    {
    tshock_msg(player, "/ielvel subcmd1");
    tshock_msg(player, "/ilevel subcmd2");
    return;
}
switch (args[0]) {
    case "subcmd1":
        tshock_exec(player, "/item 6 1");
        break;
    case "subcmd2":
        tshock_exec(player, "/item 6 1");
        break;
}
}
```

The "/ilevel subcmd1" and "/ilevel subcm2" only shows up if the player executes /ilevel subcmd1, but the tshock_exec(player, "/item 6 1"); doesn't get executed.
I have no idea how to proceed further I tried everything I know and it's still not working as it should.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `if (args <1)` ... `args[0]` - so which is it? Is `args` supposed to be a number or an array?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `args` is supposed to be an array of strings, in `ilevelSwitch`, you want to change `args < 1` to `args.length < 1`.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. Changed it to args.lenght < 1 , now after executing /ilevel it drops a "No matching indexer found." error.

Comment: You have not provided enough code to help with that.